# AutoMapper non-destructive list reconciliation?

Tags: c#, data-structures, orm, automapper, automapper-2

I have a list on the target object that I want to reconcile against the source.

The list is already created, I just want AutoMapper to add/update/delete items from this list, at no time should the list be set to a new object reference. How can I do this?

The reason for this is that the target object is an ORM generated code, and for whatever reason it has no setter.

The target looks like this:

```
 public class Target
 {
      //This is the target member.
      public List EntityList
      {
           get{
                return _entityList;
           }
      }

      //Except this is a much more complicated, track-able list
      private List _entityList= new List(); 
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

From my experience, AutoMapper isn't really designed with mapping onto already populated objects in mind. But one way to do what you're asking is to configure AutoMapper to ignore the `EntityList` property for mapping, then use `AfterMap` to call some custom reconciliation function you write to align the two lists:

```
Mapper.CreateMap<Source, Target>()
              .ForMember(dest => dest.EntityList, opt => opt.Ignore())
              .AfterMap((src, dest) => Reconcile(src.EntityList, dest.EntityList));
```